# Android notifications fail after app update because resource ids changed

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an app where I set notifications with NotificationCompat.Builder. But after an update of the app, the notifications set before the update will not be shown by Android.
The log shows this error message:

```
Unable to load resource 0x7f070027 from pkg=xx.mypackage
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable xx.mypackage:dimen/abc_disabled_alpha_material_dark with resource ID #0x7f070027
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "xx.mypackage:dimen/abc_disabled_alpha_material_dark" (7f070027) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x4/d=0x3e99999a a=6 r=0x7f070027}
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:995)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:729)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1096)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:1051)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:381)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:334)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableAsUser(Icon.java:456)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:491)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:475)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDrawable(StatusBarIconView.java:437)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.set(StatusBarIconView.java:397)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.notification.icon.IconManager.setIcon(IconManager.kt:249)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.notification.icon.IconManager.createIcons(IconManager.kt:123)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.notification.collection.inflation.NotificationRowBinderImpl.inflateViews(NotificationRowBinderImpl.java:148)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.notification.NotificationEntryManager.addNotificationInternal(NotificationEntryManager.java:619)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.notification.NotificationEntryManager.addNotification(NotificationEntryManager.java:646)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.notification.NotificationEntryManager$2.onNotificationPosted(NotificationEntryManager.java:386)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.NotificationListener.lambda$onNotificationPosted$1(NotificationListener.java:131)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.NotificationListener.lambda$onNotificationPosted$1$NotificationListener(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.-$$Lambda$NotificationListener$NvFmU0XrVPuc5pizHcri9I0apkw.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8645)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

But I don't have a resource called "abc_disabled_alpha_material_dark" and never had it. I find it mentioned in [a file of AppCompat](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/dimens_material.xml) but I have no idea how this relates to my app and the update. Notifications set after the update are shown with no problems.

### UPDATE

I found out that this error occurs because the resource ids have changed in the updated app. #0x7f070027 was the id of the drawable for the notification set with notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(). Now it is the resource id of a dimension.

I still don't know how I can prevent this from happening. I can update all notifications after an update when the user starts the app again. But all notifications between the update and the next start of the app will fail.